# what happens if an application open more than one connection to syslog?

Tags: c, linux, syslog

I have an application that uses `syslog` for logging. another library within this application explicitly calls `openlog()` for its own usage, in this case something strange happens: stderr output is sent to a tcp socket I already opened.
When I change the lib's output log to `stderr` or `stdout` everything works fine.
I was wondering if this a problem with two `syslog` connection or is it just a mess-up somewhere in the code?

This is syslog initialisation of the main app:

```
openlog( "app", LOG_PID|LOG_NDELAY, LOG_LOCAL1 );
```

This is syslog initialisation of the lib:

```
openlog("lib", LOG_CONS | LOG_PID | LOG_NDELAY, LOG_LOCAL1);
```

Answer (score 1):

It is probably implementation dependent. If you use [MUSL libc](http://musl-libc.org/) the code is here in [syslog.c](http://git.musl-libc.org/cgit/musl/tree/src/misc/syslog.c?) an you can see that only one fd is used for syslog (so two `openlog`-s are sharing the same `log_fd`). Look into [GNU libc](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/) source code to see what happens on most Linux implementations. You might also investigate with `strace` or `ltrace`